# NJsonSchema object validation

Tags: c#, njsonschema

I can't validate a json string starting from a very simple schema. This is my object type:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyPerson : Person
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my test:

```
JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.FromType(typeof(MyPerson));
var errors = schema.Validate(@"{'Surname':'Pippo','Name':'Pluto'}");
```

I always get the error:

```
{
    NotAllOf:#/
          {NoAdditionalPropertiesAllowed: #/Surname}
          {NoAdditionalPropertiesAllowed: #/Name}
}
```

Can someone help me? How should the json string be composed?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As minimum, strings must be in double quotes.